How can I draw an ellipse and circle having only one contact point?
Let $(O)$ be a circle  with center $O(0,0)$, radius $5$ and two points $P(6, 8)$, $Q(3, 10)$ are outside the circle. Find the points $T$ on $(O)$ so that the sum $TP + TQ$ get maximum and minimum and draw the ellipse( here $P$, $Q$ are the two foci) like this picture.

I tried
Clear["Global`*"]
P = {6, 8};
Q = {3, 10};
r = 5;
T = {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]};
mymin = NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[P, T] + EuclideanDistance[Q, T], 
    0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, t];
mymax = NMaximize[{EuclideanDistance[P, T] + EuclideanDistance[Q, T], 
    0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, t];
tmax = T /. mymax[[2]]
tmin = T /. mymin[[2]]
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, r], PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[P], 
  Point[Q], Point[tmax], Point[tmin]}]



https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308195/circle-rolling-on-ellipse

I suppose A, B, C are P, Q, T in some random order? The question could be made clearer, yes? The ellipse does not pass through P or Q, so maybe A, B, C are different from P, Q, T?

@MichaelE2 A, B, C are similar to P, Q, T.

"Similar" makes no sense mathematically. Please clarify.

@MichaelE2 Edited.

Your text still involves $A$ and $B$. Also, as pointed out by Michael E2, the ellipse does not pass through $P$ or $Q$. Please clarify the question. It'll be reopened once it becomes clear enough.

@cvgmt You're so kind, but: 1. $A$ and $B$ are still there. 2. We need the confirmation from OP that this is indeed what (s)he means.


ContourPlot. We set the focus to be P= {-1, 8};Q= {5, 6};

Clear["Global`*"]
(*P={6,8};
Q={3,10};*)
P = {-1, 8};
Q = {5, 6};
r = 5;
f[x_, y_] := 
  EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, P] + EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, Q];
sol1 = Minimize[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, r]}, {x, 
    y}];
sol2 = Maximize[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, r]}, {x, 
    y}];
T = {x, y} /. sol1[[2]];
S = {x, y} /. sol2[[2]];

ellips = 
  ContourPlot[
   EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, P] + 
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, Q] == {sol1[[1]], 
     sol2[[1]] // Thread}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50];
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, r], PointSize[Large], Blue, 
  Point[{P, Q, T, S}], ellips[[1]]}, PlotRange -> All]



Just a variant:
gs[a_, b_, rad_, rg_] := Module[{t, xp, d, r, ell, cp},
  xp = Norm[rad {Cos[t], Sin[t]} - a] + Norm[rad {Cos[t], Sin[t]} - b];
  {d, r} = Minimize[xp, t];
  ell = Norm[{x, y} - a] + Norm[{x, y} - b] == d;
  cp = rad {Cos[t], Sin[t]} /. r;
  ContourPlot[ell, {x, -rg, rg}, {y, -rg, rg}, 
   Epilog -> {Point[{{0, 0}, a, b, cp}], Text["O", {0, 0}, {-2, 0}], 
     Text["A", a, {-2, 0}], Text["B", b, {-2, 0}], 
     Text["C", cp, {-2, -2}], Circle[{0, 0}, rad]}]]

Using the test a,b from other answers:
a = {6, 8};
b = {3, 10};
gs[a, b, 5, 15]
gs[{-1, 8}, {5, 6}, 5, 10]




Using computational geometry:
problem = 
 GeometricScene[{{o -> {0, 0}, t1, t2, p -> {-1, 8}, 
    q -> {5, 6}}, {r -> 5}},
  {Circle[o, r],
   AngleBisector[{p, t1, q}] == InfiniteLine[{o, t1}],
   AngleBisector[{p, t2, q}] == InfiniteLine[{o, t2}],
   EuclideanDistance[o, t1] == r,
   EuclideanDistance[o, t2] == r,
   EuclideanDistance[t1, t2] > r
   }];

sol = RandomInstance[problem];

Show[sol["Graphics"], With[{
   L1 = (EuclideanDistance[p, t1] + EuclideanDistance[q, t1]),
   L2 = (EuclideanDistance[p, t2] + EuclideanDistance[q, t2])},
  Graphics[{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Gray],
     GeometricTransformation[
      Ellipsoid[(p + q)/2, {L1/2, 
        Sqrt[(L1/2)^2 - (EuclideanDistance[p, q]/2)^2]}], 
      RotationTransform[{{1, 0}, q - p}, (p + q)/2]],
     GeometricTransformation[
      Ellipsoid[(p + q)/2, {L2/2, 
        Sqrt[(L2/2)^2 - (EuclideanDistance[p, q]/2)^2]}], 
      RotationTransform[{{1, 0}, q - p}, (p + q)/2]]} /. sol["Points"]]
  ],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]



For general RandomInstance[], one might want to add [o, p] > r, EuclideanDistance[o, q] > r or there can be four solutions for the tangency criterion, and the code seeks only two.
